# Retornar Json com XMLHttpRequest

Tags: c#, jquery

Como popular um table com um `JSON` usando `XMLHttpResquest POST`?

> Jquery

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/EnvioEmail/PlanilhaPaciente", { area: "Sistema" }, true);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", function (Lista) {
           //table que recebera o resultado do json
            $('#conteudo-lista-envio-manual').html(Lista);
        }, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", function (Lista) {
            msgErro;
        }, false);
        xhr.send(formdata);
```

> C#

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PlanilhaPaciente(HttpPostedFileBase planilha)
    {
        if (Request.Files["planilha"].ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var pacientes = new ContatosEmailModelView();
            var msgerro = "";
            if (ValidaPlanilha(planilha, out pacientes, out msgerro))
                return Json(new { erro = false, Lista = pacientes.ListaContatos }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            else
                return Json(new { erro = true, msgErro = msgerro }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        return Json(new { erro = true, msgErro = "Não existe registro no arquivo" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito simples, se puder detalhar mais, como por exemplo, postar o objeto javascript que vai para essa requisição. E se existe algum objeto no server que representa o seu objeto view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi. Criar função geraBody com each para gerar as tags tr e td na table passando valor

```
this.carregaPlanilha = function () {
        var vPlanilha = $('#FileUpload')[0].files[0];

        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append('planilha', vPlanilha);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/EnvioEmail/PlanilhaPaciente", { area: "Sistema" }, true);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", function (Lista) {
            var pacientes = Lista.currentTarget.response;
            $("#conteudo-lista-envio-manual tbody").append(me.geraBody(JSON.parse(pacientes).Lista));
        }, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", function (Lista) {
            msgErro;
        }, false);
        xhr.send(formdata);
    };
```

Comment: só faltou incluir a função `geraBody()` em sua resposta ;)